# Dictionary operation order

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm using a mutable data structure and noticed that doing `d[mods_mutable()] = mods_mutable()]` doesn't have the same behaviour as

```
key = mods_mutable()
d[key] = mods_mutable()
```

It's easy to guess what's happening. A quick trip to a temporary file and a small test confirms:

```
x = 0
def f():
    global x
    x += 1
    return x

d = dict()
d[f()] = f()
print d
```

Running it, we get `{2: 1}`. Clearly the value for the key is evaluated second which kind of makes sense (as what's the point of making the key if we get an exception or such getting the value?).

Is this behaviour documented? I was unable to find anything on the official docs and Googling did nothing for my question either. Are we guaranteed this order no matter the implementation and version? Are there more gotchas like this to look-out for?

Comment: The right hand side is always evaluated first.

Comment: I can't believe I haven't thought about this…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Python evaluates expressions from left to right. Notice that *while evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side is evaluated before the left-hand side*.

See [5.14. Evaluation order](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order)